# Process enqueued job with cron job - Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, job-scheduling

I have a Ruby on Rails application that receives webhooks from Twilio, I don't want to process these webhooks immediately. What I want is:

- Enqueue webhooks in the Redis queue
- Schedule a cron-job to get jobs from the queue after a specific interval and process them based on some condition
- This will process jobs after specific intervals and I will be able to control the frequency of corn jobs to process jobs.

The application already has a working setup of Sidekiq with Redis, but I'm unable to find a way to enqueue jobs and perform later with the help of corn job.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve the above functionality? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

- Create a new model for example TwilioResponse that holding the data posting to your webhook, probably with a flag to indicate if it has been processed.
- Whenever data coming, create a new instance of that model and save into the database
- Schedule cronjob for a task to grab all unprocessed TwilioResponse instances and process them, this maybe moved to Sidekiq or just process directly in the task
- After process a TwilioResponse model, set the flag to processed

Comment: I thought of this approach but I don't want to use the database as it will keep growing with time and I might have to clean up the database periodically. And the whole point of using Redis in our case is to avoid as many databases call as possible.